# Animating div sliding from 100% of div width on x axis

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have an invisible square2 div positioned to the left of square1. I'm using GSAP to animate square1 moving to the left, then after that I want to separately animate square2 slowly sliding out of square1.

I got the first part of the animation working, but I'm not unable to figure out how to get square2 to slide out of it.

I'm trying to position square2 100% of the div's width to the right, make it visible, then animate it moving to the left. This is my attempt.

I don't believe the visibility setting is necessary since GSAP should make it visible automatically, but I included it in case anyone thought the visibility settings were the issue.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/SquanchyHappy/pen/rNmKJdJ

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="square1"></div>
<div id="square2"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 200px;
}

#square1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```
gsap.registerPlugin("MotionPathPlugin");

slideAnimation();

function slideAnimation() {
  let tl = gsap.timeline({ delay: 1 });
  tl.set(square2, { xPercent: 50, transformOrigin: "0% 50%" });
  tl.from(
    square2,
    { x: screen.width, ease: "none", duration: 0.5 },
    0
  );
  tl.from(
    square2,
    {
      y: square2.getBoundingClientRect().top - 300,
      ease: "none",
      duration: 0.5
    },
    0
  );
  tl.to(square2, {
    xPercent: 0,
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "power2",
    clearProps: "transform"
  });
  //Below is the part I can't figure out
  //square2.style.visibility = 'visible'
  //tl.set(square2, {xPercent: 100})
  //tl.from(square2, {duration: 3})
}
```

Comment: Hi there - you're more likely to get help over in the [GSAP forums.](https://greensock.com/forums/)

You can use xPercent or yPercent to move elements by a percentage of their own width or height. 

I would advise using autoAlpha instead of style.visibility

(You also don't define the square2 var anywhere.)